# Converting Chrome Extension to Firefox

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

We have a fully working extension on chrome which we are trying to get working in Firefox.  It has a background, content and popup script each sending messages to each other.

We have loaded this using about:debugging as a Temporary Extension. However, in Firefox when we try to send any messages to the content script we get this error:

> Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not establish connection.
>   Receiving end does not exist.

We use the following code to send a message to all tabs:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
                let lastTabId = tabs[0].id;
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(lastTabId, imessage);
            });
```

This gives us the could not establish error but if I change it to:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
                let lastTabId = tabs[0].id;
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(lastTabId, imessage);
            });
```

Then we no longer get the error but we want to broadcast to all tabs, this works without issue in Chrome.

In addition to the above, when we try to send a message from the popup we get:

> TypeError: chrome.tabs is undefined (we have also tried browser with the same error)

I have logged out browser and chrome when running in Firefox and tabs is not present but running in chrome it is within popup.js.

Are security restrictions greater in Firefox preventing the popup.js from accessing tabs?  We have added tabs as a permission in our manifest.

Below is the browser object in Firefox which is missing tabs but not in Chrome.

[image]

UPDATE:
After a lot of experimentation it seems that the popup in chrome is behaving like a background script with all the privileges and permissions that the background has but in Firefox it is behaving like a content script and has no access to chrome.tabs.

Manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "<removed>",
"description": "<removed>",
"author": "<removed>",
"version": "1",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",        
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "storage",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
"options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<removed>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/vendor.js",
            "js/content_script.js"
        ]
    }
],
"browser_action": {

},
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "js/vendor.js",
        "js/background.js"
    ]
},
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.html",
    "content/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

}

Also we don't use the popup as a popup, we load this in the content script and inject into the page like so as a sidebar.  Could this change the popup to be more like a content script and not have access to browser.tabs or chrome.tabs.

```
private buildSidebar() {
    this._logger.logTimeStart("buildSidebar");
    this._logger.logInfo("Build iframe sidebar");

    if (this.hasSidebarBeenInititalise()) {
        return;
    }

    let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = "extension-sidebar";
    iframe.height = "100%";
    iframe.style.background = "#CCC";
    iframe.style.height = "100%";
    iframe.style.width = "0px";
    iframe.style.position = "fixed";
    iframe.style.top = "0px";
    iframe.style.right = "0px";
    iframe.style.zIndex = "9999999999999999999999";
    iframe.frameBorder = "none";
    iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL(`popup.html?contentScriptIdentifier=${
        this._uniqueIdentifier}&currentUrl=${document.URL}`);

    this._logger.logInfo("Append iframe sidebar");
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug in Firefox, which is not surprising as its WebExtensions API still has quite a few of them. Try using their new [sidebarAction API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/sidebarAction) instead.

Comment: I suspect the original issue (the "Cannot establish connection" error) is that some of the tabs you're trying to send a message to don't have your content script injected (which could be various reasons, they could be lazy tabs, they could contain a page that does not allow content scripts, etc)

Your popup page should have access to the same APIs any extension page (including the background page) have access to (including the tabs API).  Is your complete extension available somewhere?  I don't understand what you meant by the "Also we don't use the popup as a popup" remark.